# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError in ec2 server

Tags: django, linux, amazon-ec2, server, pip

i'm typing the following in my working amazon ec2 linux server. (with ENV activated)

```
pip install pillow
```

getting this error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ec2-user/env/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/Pillow-5.1.0.dist-info'. 
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

if i use --user i get:
    Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.

Comment: Are you doing this as `ec2-user`? Did you create the virtualenvironment as `ec2-user` (or using say `sudo`)?

Comment: @BenjaminHicks Yes  i'm doing this as ec2-user. I can't remember if i created the env as ec2 or using sudo.. how can i figure it out?
Thank you for your reply!

Comment: `ls -al ~ec2-user/env` and see what you get. If the owner is someone other than `ec2-user`, you have your answer.

Comment: Thank you! i get this :        
`total 32
drwxr-xr-x 7 root     root     4096 May 17 12:01 .
drwx------ 7 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 May 31 17:14 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root     4096 May 17 12:04 bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 May 17 11:57 include
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root     4096 May 17 11:57 lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     root        3 May 17 11:57 lib64 -> lib
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 May 17 11:57 local
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       61 May 17 11:57 pip-selfcheck.json
drwxr-xr-x 9 root     root     4096 May 31 17:12 server
`
but i still cannot understand...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your answers, what happened is that you used `sudo` when you created the virtualenv so root owns it.

`sudo chown ec2-user:ec2-user -R ~ec2-user/env` will fix this and make `ec2-user` the owner of the directory (and subdirectories) again.